# Setting body background-image inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the background image of the document body when my app component renders. The image is in the same directory as the js file however it doesn't appear.

I have the following code.

**App.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'; 
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const bg = "./clouds.png";

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bg}')`;

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`clouds.png` is in the `src` directory along with `App.js`

Comment: Not sure without more code/HTML structure. I'd check the console to see if the correct image is loading? If it is you might not have a height for your body. Setting a background image does not give the container a height if there is no other content inside.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. Is there any error? do you return some HTML code?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `import` the image.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import bg from "./clouds.png";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bg}')`;
  }, []);
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

check this out:
[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hellman-scgib?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const bg = require("../assets/img/your-image.png");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bg})`;
```

Comment: Still no luck. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Are you sure that the path you define is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use an imported svg image with a specific component.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import someImage from './some-image.svg';

const SomeComponent = props => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${someImage})`;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} />
  );
};
```